# Intellij16:Why the scala source code has grammatical errors in intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

Today I want to see scala source code using intellij,when I see HashMap class I found intellij has grammatical errors,scala source code must be correct,I want to know why intellij has grammatical errors here

[image]

It's show '`reassignment to val`' error

Comment: I also encountered this problem.

Comment: @Ramesh Maharjan As discussed in an answer you later deleted, this is Scala source code and it compiles fine. `e` is a `DefaultEntry` defined as `final class DefaultEntry[A, B](val key : A, var value : B)`, so its `value` is clearly defined as a var, hence the mutability. IntelliJ is acting weird, which is not an uncommon thing.

Comment: @slouc :) yeah I didn't read the question correctly. so that was stupid answer so i deleted it. :) I checked in mine and it compiles as you said but I have val in DefaultEntry as `final class DefaultEntry[A, B](val key : A, val value : B)`

Comment: Is that problem still present in IDEA 2017.1 or 2017.2? If not, it is probably just a bug in the scala plugin that has already been fixed in newer versions. Otherwise, you might want to issue a bug.

Comment: @Ramesh Maharjan No problem :) BTW here's the class: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/collection/mutable/DefaultEntry.html (note `var value: B` )